# Resultado PHP en tabla Agrega una linea en blanco

Tags: php, html, sql, css, tablas

Estimados quisiera que me ayuden porfavor.

1. Tengo el siguiente código de conexion:

...

```
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');

define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');

define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');

define('DB_DATABASE', 'base');

$db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
```

...

2. tengo la siguiente consulta a mi tabla

...

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios_admin";

$result = $db->query($query);
```

...

3. Y el siguiente loop

   ```
                                         <?php do { ?>

                                            <tr>
                                                <td><?php echo $usuarios["nombre"]; ?></td>
                                                <td><?php echo $usuarios["cargo"]; ?></td>
                                                <td><?php echo $usuarios["region"]; ?></td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <div class="form-button-action">
                                                        <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-link btn-primary btn-lg" data-original-title="Ediar Usuario">
                                                            <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                                                        </button>
                                                        <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-link btn-danger" data-original-title="Eliminar Usuario">
                                                            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                                                        </button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>

                                               <?php } while($usuarios = $result-> fetch_assoc() > ); $db->close(); ?>
   ```
4. EL PROBLEMA : la consulta y el resultado funciona, pero al comienzo de la tabla, me arroja un espacio en blanco que no puedo quitar.

[image: la primera linea esta vacía]

Si alguien me puede ayudar con el codigo y regalar una solución.

Sinceramente espero que me puedan restar ayuda, es posible que tenga que actualizar alguna consulta o arreglo, pero soy principiante en esto.

Saludos.
Rodrigo.

Comment: Te lo muestra porque al entrar al DO no has ejecutado fetch_assoc() por lo cual la variable $usuarios no tiene datos. Adicional re recomiendo que todo lo que sea código lo agregue como tal y no como imágenes.

Comment: En lugar de capturas de pantalla debes inclulir el código como texto formateado:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Estimados, habia tratado de ingresar el codigo pero no podia, he podido adjuntar los fragmentos, epero adaptarme pronto al sistema.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estimados lo he solucionado de la siguiente forma, se que puede haber una mas sencilla, pero es lo que me funció.

Efectivamente pasaba por el do {

pero la solución fue la figuiente :

```
                                    while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                                    echo ' <tr> ';
                                    echo '<td>'.$registro[nombre]. '</td>';
                                    echo '<td>'.$registro[cargo]. '</td>';
                                    echo '<td>'.$registro[region]. '</td>';
                                    echo '<td>';
                                    echo '<div class="form-button-action"><button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-link btn-primary btn-lg" data-original-title="Ediar Usuario"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button><button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-link btn-danger" data-original-title="Eliminar Usuario"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></div>';
                                    echo '</td>';
                                    echo '</tr>';
    
                                             } ?>
```

[image: resultado]

la misma conexión, la misma consulta, solo cambié la forma del ciclo.

Saludos.
Rodrigo

Answer (score 0):

Eso es por el funcionamiento del do/while, primero realiza la acción y luego hace la validación, te recomiendo uses un for each para estos casos en lugar del do/while, algo de documentacion: [do/while](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.do.while.php) y [for each](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Javi, es genial que quieras ayudar, pero recuerda que las respuestas deben seguir ciertas reglas para evitar que sean reportadas y/o retiradas. Revisa [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que te des una idea de lo que te comento.

Comment: he actualizado el post con los código y he eliminado las imágenes, si alguien me puede ayudar a solucionarlo, la verdad es que me he atrasado y me ha tomado mas tiempo de lo debido... ya no pienso mucho y me he liado con este problema.

Saludos y desde ya muchas gracias !

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma de expresar lo mismo pero con menos echo's...

```
while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                                    echo ' <tr> 
                                            <td>'.$registro[nombre]. '</td>
                                            <td>'.$registro[cargo]. '</td>
                                            <td>'.$registro[region]. '</td>
                                            <td>
                                    <div class="form-button-action"><button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-link btn-primary btn-lg" data-original-title="Ediar Usuario"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button><button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-link btn-danger" data-original-title="Eliminar Usuario"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></div>
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>

                                    ';
    
                                             }
```

Saludos
Rodrigo